# cross browser tooltip for ruby on rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, tooltip

Which cross browser tooltip tools/plugins/components are available for ruby on rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more or less an issue for your frontend, not for Rails. If you use Prototype (which is built in into RoR) have a look at [this](http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/prototip2/). If you want to use jQuery, then [this is great](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/download).

Both tools work (in their simplest use case) by displaying the `title` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

This is not something you need to do on the backend. Just declare a standard tooltip with the title attribute

```
<span title="this is my tooltip">foo</span>
```

and style it on the frontend. [A nice jQuery plugin to style tooltips](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/).

Comment: helpful reminder if you're looking for something quick and easy, thanks